# Navigation bar hidden after back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I have an issue after clicking on the back button.

I have a first view embedded in a NavigationController with an imageView.
The navigation bar is customized with this following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // color the navigation bar and text
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.24, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

When user taps on the imageView, the following code is executed:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("view2", sender: self)
```

It is a `show(push)` segue.

When user taps on `Back button` in view2, it returns to first view but the navigation bar has disappeared!

I think it is masked by something because I can see it during debug by clicking on `Debug View Hierarchy`.

Last point, if I replace the imageView tap action to go to view2 by a simple bar button and perform the segue in storyboard and not in the code, the issue does not appear.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Not sure though can you try this ?? self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false ?? My guess may be it's set to true by any reason and when you tap on imageView it might be hiding :) just a guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it!

I realized that in view2, I make the navigation bar translucent with the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the navigation bar translucent
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

So to fix the bug, just remove the translucent attribute before disappearing the view:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Hope that helps someone one day :)

Answer (score 0):

place this code:

```
// color the navigation bar and text
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.24, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

in viewWillAppear

Comment: Just tested it but the navigation bar is still hidden after back button.